# Shelosha Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reportedly](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0016_0_15684.html), 183 Jews of Pforzheim, Germany, were deported to [Gurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurs_concentration_camp#Jews_deported_from_Baden) during the Holocaust.

Answer (score 1):

[It is claimed in fiction](http://books.google.com/books?id=_GrE78R3eJQC&pg=PR7&dq=1943), but appears to be a true fact reported in fiction (but I'm not sure), that 183 Jews of Ferrara, Italy, were deported to Germany during the Holocaust.